# Deadlocks in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have a 15 GB SQL Server database, and one of the tables contains approximately one million records. Every day, I encounter deadlocks on this table due to multiple clients attempting to write simultaneously. Since this table is crucial, these deadlocks have a negative impact on the entire system.

What strategies can I employ to address this issue?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. Add information for a specific deadlock to your question, including DDL (with indexes), query, and the deadlock report. Frequent deadlocks are often a symptom that query/index tuning is needed (queries touch more  data than needed) but can be due to application design as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please also share the query plans for the queries which are deadlocking, via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan